# 3rd Array element does not print out when using a pointer variable to assign array element values

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

SO I was reading a book on C and came across a piece of code which I couldn't fully understand, so I decided to run it out and see the result for myself. Basically, I understand that an array variable acts like a pointer, in the sense, that it points to the first element of the array, for instance.

```
char quote[]="This is a nice cookie!"
```

Here quote which is an array variable, is basically a pointer to the first element of the array i.e.  the letter T(Hope I am correct so far).

Building on this, when I write the below piece of code, I understand the following points.

1. At the declaration time, contestants is an array with 3 members in it - 1, 2 and 3
2. Then I use *choice as an array variable which in other words is a pointer to the first element of array contestants- which is now (1).
3. Now I begin dynamically assigning values to the members of the contestants array.

   contestansts[2]=*choice

puts the value 0 in the 3rd member of the array i.e.: `contestants[2]`.

So far, so good. 
Now, the next for loop was not there in the book. I included it in the code myself, to see what are the elements of the array. When I run the code, as an output I get-

```
I will pick contestant number 2
The members of the array contestants are:
Member 0 has the value 2
Member 1 has the value 3
```

My question is- I do not understand how the member 1 has the value 3. According to the code, shouldn't members 1 and 2 both have the same value(2).

Any help would be highly appreciated. 
I am using Sublime Text and the Mac terminal to run this(if needed).

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int contenstants[]={1,2,3};
    int *choice=contenstants;
    contenstants[0]= 2;
    contenstants[1]=contenstants[2];
    contenstants[2]=*choice;
    printf("\n I will pick contestant number %i\n", contenstants[2] );

    //Print array members

    printf(" The members of the array Contenstants are:\n");

    for(int i=0;i<contenstants[2];i++)
    {
        printf(" Member %i\t  has the value %i\t", i, contenstants[i] );
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int contenstants[]={1,2,3};
int *choice=contenstants;        // choice -> {1,2,3}
contenstants[0]= 2;              // choice -> {2,2,3}
contenstants[1]=contenstants[2]; // choice -> {2,3,3}
contenstants[2]=*choice;         // choice -> {2,3,2}
```

The output you get is totally logical!
In the first step you assign the value 2 to `contenstants[0]`, which is also `*choice`.

The reason why you are only getting two numbers on the output is, that you loop `for(int i=0;i<contenstants[2];i++)`, which is equivalent to `for(int i=0;i<2;i++)`, which loops over element number 0 and element number 1.

Comment: Okay, thank you! But why does the for loop only print 2 members-0 and 1. What about member 3? Shouldn't that also be printed with value 2?

Comment: I'm sorry- my mistake. The for loop should have a <=, not just a =.

Comment: @DarkKnight I updated the answer, but you are right, either use `<=` or loop over 0 to 3 (hard coded).

Answer (score 2):

It is `3` because you are doing

```
contenstants[1]=contenstants[2];
```

and then `contenstants[1]` is not modified later so it has value `3`;

To answer your question in comment:

Condition in your for loop is not correct

```
--------------v not correct
for(int i=0;i<contenstants[2];i++)
```

You want

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
```

Although using hardcoded `3` is also not a good idea. But it goes with your other code.

Comment: I see, but why doesn't the for loop print out all my array members? Only members 1 and 2 with their values are printed? And, thank you so much!

Comment: I'm sorry- my mistake. The for loop should have a <=, not just a =.